# Sync game user progress across devices - unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, facebook-login

I have a really simple game on both iOS and Android written in **Unity** and I would like to save user progress across devices/OSes.

I already have Facebook analytics in it and so i was thinking i can implement Facebook Login and just save a couple of numbers on the Facebook server.

Upon some research it seems (?) that Facebook doesn't offer anything like that. You have to set up your own server and then just identify the player with Facebook login. A server like that is really an overkill for the game as i just want to save a simple **Level Passed number**.

Is there any other way? Can i use Facebook like that to save ONE custom user property? Perhaps i can use Google Play Services (both iOS and Android (?) ) to achieve what i want?

Any other free way of saving user progress across devices?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution?

Comment: Yes, i implemented a very simple solution on Firebase with FireStore

Comment: Great, thanks for following up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing Google play service stopped support for IOS

https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart

Other suggestion for Cross platform services like firebase cloud, photon, Gamesprak etc.

```
https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/
https://www.photonengine.com/
https://www.gamesparks.com/
```

Please not most of them giving free service for development only. Before use please check its price details